# Why is pdflatex automatically loading a ConTeXt package and crashing

Tags: pdftex, color, context

If I process the following MWE with pdflatex (TeXLive 2012, Linux)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\def\mymacro#1{#1}
\begin{document}
\pdfinfo{/Title (Some text \textbf{This macro causes problems})}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

I get an error from  ../texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii. That seems to be a ConTeXt file. The error is

> ```
> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
> \@@mpstopdf@@unprotect ... \@@mpstopdf@@unprotect 
>                            \unprotect \let \@@mpstopd...
> l.34     \def\unprotect
>
> !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
> ```

It also happens if I load `xcolor`, but not if I load `graphicx` or any other package I have tried. While it is not specific to `\textbf`, I don't get the problem with `\mymacro`.

What is going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not specific to `\textbf` but `\pdfinfo` has to put a plain text string into the pdf data so most TeX commands will cause problems. You just want

```
\pdfinfo{/Title (Some text This macro causes problems)}
```

The graphics package loads that file to support loading metapost files, as Hans wrote it to work with any TeX flavour and there seemed no need to re-write it just because it had a context rather than latex heritage. It is unrelated to the error you get on your example. color and graphics share the same `.def` files so loading either will cause the file to be loaded.

Comment: I do not get the error if I load `graphics` or `graphicx`, but I do with `color` and `xcolor`. The fully expandable `\mymacro` doesn't cause problems. In the bigger picture I am setting `/Title` with `\@title` so eliminating the macros isn't trivial. The error message is about the redefined `\unprotect`, so it definitely seems related to supp-pdf.mkii.

Comment: `\textbf` is not fully expandable, inside LaTeX's protected expansion contexts (writing to the `.toc` file, ...) it produces itself (more or less). However `\pdfinfo` performs a hard expansion that breaks the assignments inside `\textbf`. Thus instead of defining `\@reserveda`, the previous meaning of `\@reserveda` is used (adding `supp-pdf.mkii` to the file list). To get `\textbf` into the title, you would have to use something like `\string\\textbf` (PDF strings require backslash doubling). But I don't know a PDF viewer that know about LaTeX or TeX. See also package `hyperref`.